# HTTPoison follow redirects

Tags: redirect, elixir, httpoison

There is a public API that perfectly works in the browser and returns the JSON response but using the latest version of Httpoision It does not work as expected:

HTTP (GET) : https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json?query_term=tt11296058

```
 {:ok,
 %HTTPoison.Response{
   body: "",
   headers: [
     {"Date", "Tue, 22 Jun 2021 11:42:20 GMT"},
     {"Transfer-Encoding", "chunked"},
     {"Connection", "keep-alive"},
     {"Cache-Control", "max-age=3600"},
     {"Expires", "Tue, 22 Jun 2021 12:42:20 GMT"},
     {"Location",
      "https://yts.mx/api/v2/list_movies.json?query_term=tt11296058"},
     {"cf-request-id", "0ad5205cb800004da508b04000000001"},
     {"Expect-CT",
      "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\""},
     {"Report-To",
      "{\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v2?s=O80%2B5KfZ6d3G3Fz0NBGlep%2BetzQAvaUDIvVW09DUB2QMtJpd1XxupK621LhGR8EqiOsOY%2B55BdaHAljyLCEumHyb0rHSqk526jMQ5NxuLUi%2FVdbX\"}],\"group\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}"},
     {"NEL", "{\"report_to\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}"},
     {"Server", "cloudflare"},
     {"CF-RAY", "663536745c654da5-BOM"},
     {"alt-svc",
      "h3-27=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-28=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-29=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3=\":443\"; ma=86400"}
   ],
   request: %HTTPoison.Request{
     body: "",
     headers: [],
     method: :get,
     options: [],
     params: %{},
     url: "https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json?query_term=tt11296058"
   },
   request_url: "https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json?query_term=tt11296058",
   status_code: 301
 }}
```

Also to point out the status_code is coming from the response is 301.
301 is for a resource that is permanently removed, but it seems that is not the case here.

project dependencies:

```
Elixir: 1.12.1
OTP: 24
{:httpoison, "~> 1.8"},
{:floki, "~> 0.20.4"},
{:poison, "~> 3.1"},
{:hackney, github: "benoitc/hackney", override: true},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 301 is for a resource that is permanently removed

Absolutely not. This is a [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_redirection) (code for “Moved Permanently.”)

The browser obviously handles redirections itself, the code must handle it on its own. Upon receiving `301` your code should repeat the request by the location specified. In the response you provided, there is no location specified in the response, which is weird, but that’s another issue.

---

`HTTPoison` can be [instructed to handle redirects](https://hexdocs.pm/httpoison/HTTPoison.html#request/5-redirect-handling), though.

Comment: Should not the HTTPoision be handling this?

Comment: I am not affiliated with `HTTPoison` authors in any way, so I cannot answer this particular question about whether it should or not. On how to handle redirects with `HTTPoison` I’ll update the answer now.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the `follow_redirect` option:

```elixir
HTTPoison.get(url, [], follow_redirect: true)
```

Example:

```elixir
iex(1)> Mix.install [:httpoison]
:ok
iex(2)> url = "https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json?query_term=tt11296058"
"https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json?query_term=tt11296058"
iex(3)> HTTPoison.get(url, [], follow_redirect: true)
{:ok,
 %HTTPoison.Response{
   body: "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"status_message\":\"Query was successful\",\"data\":
...
```